# Autodesk Forge TokenFlex API: POST Query BadRequestError for chargedItemID

Tags: autodesk-forge

Using Postman I find that including the chargedItemID field in a Forge TokenFlex API POST query for CLOUD_PRODUCT or DESKTOP_PRODUCT usageCategory results in a BadRequestError.  Forge API documentation indicates that this is a transactional/session level field and that you cannot mix usage categories when used in queries.  I am not doing that.  Documentation also indicates that this is a general field applicable to all usage categories.  The query works properly for the CLOUD_SERVICES category only.  Any suggestions / recommendations?

Comment: Just reached out to Engineering for comments - will get back soon

Comment: Per Engineering `chargedItemID` is as stated [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/tokenflex/v1/reference/fields-and-metrics/) applicable to only session or transaction level data, which in your case might be applicable only to `cloud_services`. Can you post the entire error response so they can look into it?

Answer (score 0):

Per the query endpoint documentation, due to large volumes you cannot query against the chargedItemId field for the CLOUD_PRODUCT and DESKTOP_PRODUCT categories. Instead you need to use the export API.

Regards, Bastien